# How to make the top of candy mountain from Kirby super star

Tags: objects

First post (yay) i know this may sound dumb but, in kirby super star theres a backround with mountains called "candy mountain" i was wondering how do you make that "spiky cone" of the mountains

http://kirby.wikia.com/wiki/Candy_Mountain

Not the base of the mountain just the tops, the "spiked" white area

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a cylinder with 24 vertices for a 12 spike object. Set the Cap Fill Type to nothing.
[image]

Tab into edit mode and select the bottom ring of vertices. From the Select menu select Checker Deselect. Now use <kbd>g</kbd> to grab the vertices and <kbd>z</kbd> to constrain the movement to the Z axis. Drag down to set the length of the spikes. In the following image I have hidden the top ring of vertices with <kbd>h</kbd>
[image]

Then extrude the top ring twice, once to create the ridge and the second time to create the top. Close this with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> and Merge to Center.

Now Tab out of edit mode. Set Smooth and add the Subdivision Surface modifier and ensure the Subdivision for both Preview and Render are 1.
[image]

Comment: oh ok, that's what I tried first, then I didn't realize that it could work with a Subdivision of only 1, maybe it could be a limitation sometimes though (?)

Comment: Is it possible that i can curve this obj. to "open up" a little more so i can fit it into the conical frustum?

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be easy, but as this object is both smooth and sharp, it is not. Maybe there's a easiest way to dot it, anyway here is mine:

- Create a plane and subdivide it vertically (for example 7 times).
- Give it an *Array* modifier and, in *Count*, choose the number of duplications (i.e. the number of spikes you'll need), for example 12. Enable the *Merge* and *First/Last* options.
- Create an Empty at the origin point of your plane.
- Give your plane a *SimpleDeform* modifier with the *Bend* option enabled and choose the Empty as *Axis, Origin*.
- In the same modifier, choose 360° as *Deform Angle* . Now your shape is a ring.
- Give your plane a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, and *Smooth* it in the *T* panel.
- In *Edit* mode begin to move up and down your vertices so that it creates spikes. Move some vertices along their edges to sharpen the top and bottom of those spikes. Now you have a kind of crown.
- Keep a copy of this object + Empty.
- Apply the *Array* modifier, then apply the *SimpleDeform* modifier. Keep the *Subsurf*.
- You need to make some corrections to join the first and the last object of the *Array* (maybe the gap is avoidable, I don't know), use <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> to merge vertices.
- Now you can begin to extrude and scale the top, then close it with a <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>.
- You can give your object a *Solidify* modifier if you want to give it thickness

[image]

Comment: I get the same result by creating a Cylinder with 24 vertices and no ends. Then in Edit mode using the Checker deselect on the bottom ring of vertices and dragging out the spikes.Then the same steps as @moonboots to create the dome top, extrude, merge, set smooth, add Subdivision Surface modifier.

Comment: could you please explain how (make an answer)? Because to have both sharp spikes and Subsurf modifier you need to work each spike, it's a bit tedious, or I'm missing something